# Подскажите в реализации php или JavaScript скрипта для шаблона ВордПресс?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Вопрос к спецам, кто пишет на языке php или JavaScript. Вопрос относится к сайту. Подскажите порядок действий, а главное функции чтобы сделать следующее:

Нужен скрипт по работе с шаблоном ВордПресс, а именно, запретить удалять копирайт из шаблона. Нужно проверить наличие копирайта на сайте и если его нет, не подключать файл стилей к сайту, если есть, то подключать.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий... Какой текст? В каком файле? Приведите примеры.

Comment: Смотрите, Эдуард. Задача вот в чем заключается. Я перевожу шаблоны на вопдпресс, не просто плагином переводчиком, а всё что не на русском ручками. Хочу поставить ссылку в копирайт шаблона свою в качестве оплаты и выкладывать их бесплатно. Но надо сделать так, что если ссылку удаляют из файла или заменяют на свою, то либо скрывать содержимое css файла либо его вообще удалять если это возможно. То есть, чтобы сайт не загружал этот файл без моего копирайта. Либо удалял файл по указанному пути, в идеале.

Comment: если кто-то удалит ваш копирайт, то ему ничего не помешает удалить то, что будет препятствовать подключению необходимых для работы сайта файлов. Поэтому, _(лично я считаю, а вы сами решайте)_ вам нужно или не заниматься добродетелью, или продолжать своё дело невзирая на удаление копирайтов.

Comment: @Эдуарда на пхп есть инструменты обфускации, которые конечно 100% результата не дадут, но какой-то процентик будет.

Comment: @Manitikyl а смысл? Есть же деобфускаторы. Более того, далеко не каждый пользователь захочет юзать кота в мешке - предпочтение всегда отдают открытому исходному коду. Иначе можно что-то обфусцированное установить, и получить уязвимость.

Comment: @Эдуард та это понятно, но есть и те кто даже с этим словом не знаком и заморачиваться не будет, не зря я написал "процентик"

Comment: Ребят, я прекрасно понимаю, что более-менее головастый сможет удалить всё, но у меня ориентир на новичков вордпресс и к тому же я намерен предупреждать об этом. Просто я так подумал, будет очень не красиво с моей стороны брать деньги за бесплатное, а так хоть какая-то польза. Поэтому и задался этим вопросом, можно ли сделать такое.

Comment: @Эдуард уже начал, благодарю.

Comment: Скорее всего вы правы ребят. Только отпугивать ЦА буду этим действием. Лучше что нибудь более адекватное придумаю для собственной пользы. Спасибо что подтолкнули. Очень благодарен.

Comment: @Эдуард [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы правы ребят. Только отпугивать ЦА буду этим действием. Лучше что нибудь более адекватное придумаю для собственной пользы. Спасибо что подтолкнули. Очень благодарен.